# How to make screen sharing on aghora.io ? in React.js ( web )

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webrtc, screensharing

Hi all I am trying to implement a conference video call application using [aghora.io](https://www.agora.io/en/)  which require screen sharing since I am using react.js ( web ) , I used the [UI kit](https://docs.agora.io/en/video-calling/get-started/get-started-uikit?platform=web)  that was provided by [aghora.io](https://www.agora.io/en/)  but It does not mention anything about screen sharing . Is there any way that I could achieve that ?

I am also facing issues like invalid token ( even though the token was generated using the server which was in the documentation [here](https://railway.app/new/template/NKYzQA?referralCode=waRWUT)  ) , I used the same appId in both my backend and frontend application still it is showing the following error

[message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FndT9.jpg)